# If we can train a ML algorithm to recognize letters with 95% accuracy, why does OCR software still suck?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, ocr

So I've seen all these leaps in machine learning alorithms these past years and they've only gotten better and better at recognizing handwritten text. I remember reading once that some algorithms have 95% accuracy. So then, why when I use an OCR software, it spits out garbage? Even with printed text, which I feel should have even better accuracy?

Comment: That's pretty  subjective.  Can you be more specific?  Have you countered/measured the number of errors?  I bet the number of errors is far smaller than 5%.  What kind of images are you working with?  Are you applying  OCR to  handwritten text or printed text?  My experience with OCR doesn't match yours -- for printed  text it seems to work fairly well, if you use the right OCR  software and start from high-quality images -- so it would help if you would give concrete numbers rather than subjective feelings (like "garbage").

Comment: 1) Research articles usually use small sets of possible letters/forms and articifial test sets. For instance, only one font and letters already extracted. 2) After improvement, this question may be a  better fit for [scicomp.SE] or [ai.SE].